# Power BI Sum of Distinct Value by Category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have n types of berries. Each berry type gets an accumulation value. I need to calculate the sum of distinct accumulation values by berry type. For "accumulation calc" (image below) I would therefore want a total of 10 (5 + 3 + 2).

- DAX formula I'm using: `accumulation calc = sumx(VALUES(berries[type]), MAX(berries[accumulation]))`
- How do I instruct DAX to sum max or distinct by individual berry types? Currently it seems to default to blueberry and calculate 5 + 5 + 5 instead of 5 + 3 + 2.

Does anyone have a hint?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want subtotal for `Max` value for each berry type, it will be better to create a `summary` table to obtain individual berry type and max value for type:

**Dax Measure for new table:**

```
Table 2 = SUMMARIZE(Sheet1,Sheet1[Berry],"Max value",
            CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[accumulation]),
              FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Berry]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Berry]))))
```

**New table:**

[image]

**Sample data:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Kin Siang - is there no way to create a measure? I'm trying to avoid creating a separate summary table.

Comment: A measure may only return `single value or text`, it is unlike you can retrieve both `Distinct type & Max value` with single measure, therefore it will be simple method to get your result and easy to track in future, accept answer if helping :)

Comment: Welcome, glad you find it useful :)